# Building windows installer in docker container using install4j and gradle

Tags: docker, install4j, bitbucket-pipelines

Install4j windows build inside docker container fails with the following error:

```
Loading config file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/_installer/_install4j/xxx.install4j
Error instantiating bean [ID: 2, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.WelcomeScreen, name: ]
java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.getInstance(SunFontManager.java:247)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:265)
        at java.desktop/sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1243)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1646)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRadioButtonUI.getPreferredSize(BasicRadioButtonUI.java:321)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1680)
        at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardScreen.<clinit>(WizardScreen.java:19)
        at com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemScreen.<clinit>(SystemScreen.java:18)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:367)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:312)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
        ... 37 more
Error instantiating bean [ID: 8, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.InstallationDirectoryScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Error instantiating bean [ID: 12, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.ComponentsScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Error instantiating bean [ID: 15, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.InstallationScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Error instantiating bean [ID: 20, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FinishedScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Error instantiating bean [ID: 24, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallWelcomeScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Error instantiating bean [ID: 27, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallationScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemProgressScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Error instantiating bean [ID: 32, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallFailureScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Error instantiating bean [ID: 30, class: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallSuccessScreen, name: ]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.getOrInstantiateBean(ejt:274)
        at com.install4j.config.a.f.I(ejt:232)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.b(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.d(ejt:331)
        at com.exe4j.b.b.n.b(ejt:49)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:381)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.ejt.framework.gui.cz.a(ejt:546)
        at com.install4j.config.n.b(ejt:368)
        at com.install4j.config.k.e(ejt:255)
        at com.exe4j.b.f.a(ejt:206)
        at com.install4j.config.k.a(ejt:269)
        at com.install4j.config.k.a(ejt:84)
        at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.f(ejt:728)
        at com.exe4j.a.g(ejt:393)
        at com.exe4j.a.a(ejt:356)
        at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:90)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.start(UnixLauncher.java:66)
        at install4j.com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1367)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1342)
        at com.ejt.framework.gui.cz.a(ejt:542)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.WelcomeScreen
        at com.install4j.config.a.a.c.a(ejt:24)
        at com.install4j.config.a.a.a.c(ejt:22)
        at com.ejt.framework.gui.cz.a(ejt:539)
        at com.install4j.config.a.a.a.a(ejt:22)
        at com.install4j.config.a.z.<init>(ejt:85)
        at com.install4j.config.n.t(ejt:456)
        at com.install4j.config.n.d(ejt:386)
        at com.install4j.config.n.f(ejt:369)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
install4j: Could not load config file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/_installer/_install....
```

I'm using `debian:jessie` as a base image. Running tests and creating the JAR works, but I'm stuck creating the installer. How can I solve this? Is what I'm trying to do possible (create windows installer inside a docker)?

I've tried to enable all the debug info in the gradle task not sure what I could try to get this running.

I also need to know will a project I setup with the gui in windows work in a linux environment?

Comment: Please try installing fontconfig.

Comment: I added the following package `apt-get install -y fontconfig-config` re-ran the build and got the same error message

Comment: It seems to be the same issue as described here at https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/issues/75 Can you try to install libfontconfig1?

Comment: `apt-get install -y libfontconfig1-dev` solved the issue. Feel free to post it as answer and I will accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install4j initializes the AWT even in headless mode and the AWT needs certain font libraries to be installed. Installing the libfontconfig1-dev package by executing

```
apt-get install -y libfontconfig1-dev
```

will fix this issue.